# Can't seem to find my null pointer problem

Tags: java, arrays, url, rss

Am i just not initializing the `AnimeItem`'s within the array correctly or is because of the way I'm sifting through the entire html code as one element not following the hierarchy of item, title, link, in correct order? Unsure to be honest, I tried a few different things but I can't seem to come up with a solution yet.

```java
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String HS = "";
    RSSReader r = new RSSReader();
    AnimeItem[] AI = r.getItems(HS);
    for(int i = 0; i < AI.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.println(AI[i].getENTRY() + ":\n" + AI[i].getTITLE() + "\n" + AI[i].getLINK());
    }
}
```

```java
public AnimeItem[] getItems(String urlAddress) {
    try {
        URL rssUrl = new URL(urlAddress);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(rssUrl.openStream()));
        String line;
        int ENTRYNUMBER = 0;

        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            if (line.contains("<item>")) {
                ENTRYNUMBER++;
                ANIMEITEMS[ENTRYNUMBER].setENTRY(ENTRYNUMBER);
            }

            if (line.contains("<title>")) {
                int firstPos = line.indexOf("<title>");
                String temp = line.substring(firstPos);
                temp = temp.replace("<title>", "");
                int lastPos = temp.indexOf("</title>");
                temp = temp.substring(0, lastPos);
                ANIMEITEMS[ENTRYNUMBER].setTITLE(temp);
            }

            if (line.contains("<link>")) {
                int firstPos = line.indexOf("<link>");
                String temp = line.substring(firstPos);
                temp = temp.replace("<link>", "");
                int lastPos = temp.indexOf("</link>");
                temp = temp.substring(0, lastPos);
                ANIMEITEMS[ENTRYNUMBER].setLINK(temp);
            }
        } 

        in.close();

        return ANIMEITEMS;
    } catch (MalformedURLException ue) {
        System.out.println("Problem with URL: " + ue);
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        System.out.println("Problem with IO: " + ioe);
    }

    System.out.println("ISSUE");
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Just now thought of this but would it work if i nested my <title> and <link> within the <item> if statement? the title and link parameters are within the item so maybe?? lol

Comment: To make it more readable, you might follow the java style guidelines. Variables start with lower case, and the names are camel-cased. getEntry() rather than getENTRY ().

Comment: Where do you get the error? Can you edit the question and put the stack trace there?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry was being pretty dumb here, found the issue just had to increase array size far beyond what i needed kept getting array out of bounds over and over lol

Comment: Final Answer: The most recent null pointer was due to my dumba**'s typo in hard coding a directory.. It didn't exist bc I never put the actual dir in correctly woops.